# How to display checkbox on view (check or not) depending on their values in database (c# .net)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, checkbox

I'm making an web app for my internship and here is my question.
I'v got a form that users have to complete (only checkboxes to check or not)
I already do the code to store the data in my database (as true/false) when they submit. 
But I also want to to display the checkbox check or not when they return on that page depending on how they have been stored in database. And I don't find/know how to do it.

Here is the code I'v make for save them in database if it could help.
Thanks!

CONTROLLER

```
if (Request.Form["submit"] != null)
        {

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-GoodFood-20171116084216.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GoodFood-20171116084216;Integrated Security=True";
                using (conn)
                {

                    String query = "UPDATE PreferencesModels SET Lait=@Lait, oeufs=@oeufs, Arachides=@Arachides, coque=@coque, sesame=@sesame, " +
                        "gluten=@gluten, soja=@soja, poisson=@poisson, crustace=@crustace, mollusques=@mollusques, moutarde=@moutarde," +
                        "diabete=@diabete, cholesterol=@cholesterol, palme=@palme" +
                            " WHERE email=@email";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lait", model.Lait);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oeufs", model.Oeufs);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arachides", model.Arachides);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coque", model.Coque);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sesame", model.Sesame);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gluten", model.Gluten);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soja", model.Soja);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poisson", model.Poisson);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@crustace", model.Crustace);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mollusques", model.Mollusques);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moutarde", model.Moutarde);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@diabete", model.Diabete);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cholesterol", model.Cholesterol);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@palme", model.Palme);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Session["email"]);

                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    return View("Scanner");
                }
               }
        }
```

VIEW

```
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="test1">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Lait)
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lait)  
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <div class="test1">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Oeufs)
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Oeufs)
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <div class="test1">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Arachides)
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Arachides)  
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
```

MODEL :

```
    [Display(Name = "Lait")]
    public bool Lait { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Oeufs")]
    public bool Oeufs { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Arachides")]
```

Comment: You'd need to read from the database first to get the data, then you can pass those values into the model and finally sending the model to the view

Comment: Yes, that completely what i think first, I do a select from the databse,  but here is where I don't know how to store them in model (I try the same as I do for storing them and It don't work) and don't know either how to pass them to the view ^^

Comment: What's your viewmodel name? You can assign checkbox values from fetched data to the viewmodel properties and use `return View("Scanner", viewmodel)`. Why using `Request.Form["submit"]` if you can use `@model` to bind viewmodel & pass it by POST action?

Comment: Oh I see a little, i'll try to make that changes (sorry I'm a begginer in .net C#)